# Get max x rows plus all row info per group by in mysql to linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, greatest-n-per-group

A while ago I found a handy query for mysql to get the top X per group by.
This is what I mean:

if this is the table:

```
rid id1 id2 id3 value
1   1   1   1   10
2   1   1   2   11
3   1   1   3   9
4   1   2   1   20
5   1   2   2   18
6   1   2   3   23
7   1   3   1   30
8   1   3   2   34
9   1   3   3   31
10  1   3   4   27
11  1   3   5   32
12  1   4   1   41
13  1   4   2   40
14  1   4   3   43
15  1   5   1   53
16  1   5   2   51
17  1   5   3   50
18  2   1   1   11
19  2   1   2   9
20  2   1   3   12
```

I want to get this result:

```
rid id1 id2 id3 value
2   1   1   2   11
6   1   2   3   23
8   1   3   2   34
14  1   4   3   43
15  1   5   1   53
```

I can get this by running the following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM idsandvalue 
   WHERE id1=1 AND 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM idsandvalue AS helper 
      WHERE helper.id1 = idsandvalue.id1 
      AND helper.id2= idsandvalue.id2 
      AND helper.value > idsandvalue.value
     ) < 1
  )a;
```

if I change < 1 to lets say 2, 3 or x I can get the top x per id2 where id1=1 (so, two of the same id2's with different id3's) like this:

```
rid id1 id2 id3 value
1   1   1   1   10
2   1   1   2   11
4   1   2   1   20
6   1   2   3   23
8   1   3   2   34
11  1   3   5   32
12  1   4   1   41
14  1   4   3   43
15  1   5   1   53
16  1   5   2   51
```

two questions.
A) the query is not really fast in MySQL. Takes a while (runs a table with 3207394 rows). Can I get the same result with the use of a different query (I was not able to get it).
B) How can I translate this to linq? Due to the strange where statement, I have no clue how to translate this into linq.

(later I added this extra question as well)
in MySQL I use this query:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS Counter FROM idsandvalue GROUP BY id1,id2;
```

to get this result:

```
rid id1 id2 id3 value   Counter
1   1   1   1   10       3
4   1   2   1   20       3
7   1   3   1   30       5
12  1   4   1   41       3
15  1   5   1   53       3
18  2   1   1   11       3
```

I'm also having difficulties translating this to Linq.

(extra info was too big for comment)

Hi John (thanks for the quick respond). 
with this mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM idsandvalue 
   WHERE id1=1 AND 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM idsandvalue AS helper 
      WHERE helper.id1 = idsandvalue.id1 
      AND helper.id2= idsandvalue.id2 
      AND helper.value > idsandvalue.value
     ) < 1
  )a
```

I try to get the rows for each grouped id1 and id2 with it's biggest value. That's why in this case I get for instance row with id 2. 11 is the biggest of 10,11 and 9 where id1=1 and id2=1. and that's why I get the row with id 8, because where id1=1 and id2=3 the biggest value for column value is 34. If I change the query to < 2, I get the top two. for id2=1 and id2=3 this would give the rows with id 8 and 11. Is this better explained?

Comment: Only 1 question tagged `greatest-n-per-group` + `linq` at the moment. [Any good to you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+linq)

Comment: seems it;'s not really working for me. (the solution you gave me in the link). Regards, Matthijs

Comment: You haven't actually described what you're trying to do. You say you want to get a particular result, but you haven't described in words what that actually means. My SQL isn't good enough to necessarily translate that query into the right concepts, even though *from* those concepts I may well be able to give the right LINQ query...

Comment: Hi John, please see the edited question. (and thanks again for the quick respond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated your table in SQL Server and ran your query against it, than converted the query via linqer:

```
from a in ((from idsandvalue in db.idsandvalue whereidsandvalue.id1 == 1 &&

    (from helper in db.idsandvalue
    where
      helper.id1 == idsandvalue.id1 &&
      helper.id2 == idsandvalue.id2 &&
      helper.value > idsandvalue.value
    select new {
      helper
    }).Count() < 1
select new {
  idsandvalue
}))
```

select new {
  a.idsandvalue.rid,
  a.idsandvalue.id1,
  a.idsandvalue.id2,
  a.idsandvalue.id3,
  a.idsandvalue.value
}

Comment: DBLinq doesn't like joins on the same table (had this issue before). But if I first get the raw result in a list and use the list as the source. It seems to be working fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
var takeRows = 2; // or whatever value you want
var q = from i in idsandvalue
        group i by new { i.ID1, i.ID2 } into g
        orderby g.Key.ID1, g.Key.ID2
        select new { g.Key.ID1, g.Key.ID2, TopValues = g.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).Take(takeRows) };
```

Comment: Are you sure MySql linq provider supports `group` and other functionality in your code?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - it didn't even occur to me that it wouldn't!

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - I usually use MS SQL, so that's my frame of reference.  I would be pretty shocked if MySql can't do "group by"...

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try tomorrow (I don't have the code now).

Comment: I get this error message:"Argument type 'RSAnalyseDB.IDSandValue' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RSAnalyseDB.IDSandValue]'" (I use DBLinq as linq provider)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much more than this; I don't have your environment.  Good luck!